# regexp to include a field

Tags: php, mysql, regex

```
 $resultInput = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table. " WHERE Field NOT IN ('id', 'created', 'date_modified', 'type', 'bodytext') AND Field NOT REGEXP '_image|content'");
```

Works... However how does one use REGEXP in this scenario to INCLUDE a specific field?

For example:

```
 $resultTextarea = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table. " WHERE Field IN ('bodytext') AND Field LIKE '%content%'");
```

(also AND Field REGEXP 'content' - Doesnt seem to work either)

Neither does now return an error, however it doesnt return the content fields I want in the form I am building from the table columns.

Comment: `Field IN ('bodytext')` is identical to `Field='bodytext'`. An `in` with a single value is rather pointless...

Answer (score 2):

You already explicitly specified that `Field` must contain exactly the string "bodytext" (`WHERE Field IN ('bodytext')`), therefore it cannot contain "content" at the same time...

Comment: How would i modify the query so that the specific field bodytext shows up and any fields that have content do as well?

Comment: @AlexFagard, `SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table WHERE Field IN ('bodytext', 'content');`. I'm really not sure what you're planning to do with regexps here.

Comment: because content is not always content it sometimes is main_content or content_short. therefore i need to do a search for content in general so i can include those fields and textareas. basically how would i combine a static bodytext with a dynamic content?

Comment: @AlexFagard, then remove `IN (...)` altogether and just use something like `WHERE Field REGEXP 'bodytext|content'` or `WHERE Field = 'bodytext' OR Field LIKE '%content%'`. You can also use your original query, just replace the `AND` with `OR`, because you want either the first thing to match *or* the second, not *both* at the same time.

Comment: yeah, like @Radu says, it sounds like you want `Field LIKE '%content%'`. I've found regexes are not so helpful as you'd hope in mysql....

Comment: Yea makes sense although not exactly what I want... but since no columns have both it doesnt matter! Nice workarond thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, just keep adding keywords in the regexp

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM Field 
WHERE Field
REGEXP 'bodytext|content'
```